# [sqlite3 and python]: how to fill up multiple column on a table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am learning database and database management with Python and I am getting crazy with a line of code to fill up multiple columns on a database from a Python interpreter.
As you can see here 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

when you want to fill up a column of a table from a line (say a string column) of code taken from the python interpreter the command you have to use is

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO
tableName
(columnName) VALUES('%s')
''' % pythonVariable )
```

How can I fill up multiple columns with the some command? I tried in many ways such as

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO
tableName
(columnName1, columnName2) VALUES('%s', '%s')
''' % pythonVariable1 pythonVariable2 )
```

or just writing the some command line two times as reported here

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO
tableName
(columnName1) VALUES('%s')
''' % pythonVariable1 )

c.execute('''INSERT INTO
tableName
(columnName2) VALUES('%s')
''' % pythonVariable2 )
```

But I failed with both of them and I am getting crazy with a so stupid issue, could you suggest me the right line of code, please?

Comment: did you commit the changes in the database?

Answer (score 2):

I would not follow the @Flippy's advice.

```
c.execute("insert into tableName values ('%s', '%s')" % (var1, var2))
```

It is not a good idea to use string formatting to pass query parameters into the query - you are becoming vulnerable to [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and may encounter type conversion issues.

Instead, **parameterize the query**:

```
c.execute("""
    INSERT INTO 
        tableName 
    VALUES 
        (?, ?)
""", (var1, var2))

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Yes, I read something like that in the webpage I mentioned before, but as I am still poor into this topic, honestly I don't see much more than a change in the syntax.
Could you explain me in which that code is more vulnerable than this one?

Comment: @StefanoFedele sure, see the `?` placeholders in the query and the comma after the query and before the parameters - this is all important since this way we are asking the `sqlite3` driver to make a parameterized query - handle the type conversions, escape the parameters to make the execution safe etc.  See more at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute.